# Weak convergence in Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces

#### Definition of the problem

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space, and let $\left(x_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathcal{H}$ be a sequence. Prove the following:

If $\left(f\left(x_{n}\right)\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathbb{K}$
converges for each $f\in\mathcal{H}^{\star}$, then there exists $x\in\mathcal{H}$
such that $\left(x_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges weakly
to $x$.

#### My idea

Define $\varphi:\mathcal{H}^{\star}\rightarrow\mathbb{K},\quad f\mapsto\lim\limits _{n\rightarrow\infty}f\left(x_{n}\right).$
We know that Hilbert spaces are reflexive, then the canonical mapping
is surjective (from $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathcal{H}^{\star\star}$).

Claim: $\varphi\in\mathcal{H}^{\star\star}$.

If we know that $\varphi\in\mathcal{H}^{\star\star}$, then $\varphi\left(f\right)=\lim\limits _{n\rightarrow\infty}f\left(x_{n}\right)=f\left(x\right)$,
since the canonical mapping is surjective.

#### My questions

How could I prove now that my $\varphi$ is an element of $\mathcal{H}^{\star\star}$?

How do you find my proof so far? Is it complete? How would you improve it?

Thanks a lot, Franck.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to prove first that $\{x_n\}_n$ is a bounded sequence. If this is true, then there exists a weakly convergent subsequence. But I guess that the whole sequence should then be convergent, too.

Comment: @Siminore But we have no assumption on $\{x_n\}_n$, apart that $\{x_n\}_n$ being in a sequence in a Hilbert space. Where would that way lead to?

Comment: But you know that $\{\langle f,x_n \rangle\}_n$ is a convergent sequence, for every $f \in H^*$. This should be an important piece of information.

Comment: Hint: Banach-Steinhaus theorem.

Comment: (Also known as Uniform Boundedness Principle)

Comment: But the UBP says that for linear bounded functionals $T_i$ from Banach spaces to subspaces of that Banach space, $\sup\limits _{i\in I}\left\Vert T_{i}\left(x\right)\right\Vert <\infty\Rightarrow\sup\limits _{i\in I}\left\Vert T_{i}\right\Vert <\infty$. But how could that help me? Could you please give me a bit more detail? I do not see how to go any further.

Comment: Identify $x_n$ with $\phi_n$ in $H^{**}$ and apply UBP. Then use that normbounded sets are weakly compact. Now go back to $H$.

Comment: @FranckStudiesCommEng: For each $x \in H$, $f \mapsto f(x)$ is a bounded linear functional on $H^*$.

Comment: We _will_ make you solve this today ;-)

Comment: The only missing step is to show that the $\phi$ you have defined is continuous. By assumption, the (single element) set $\{\phi(f)\}$ is bounded, for any $f$, so apply BS to conclude that $\phi$ is bounded. Then you are finished (using reflexivity).

Comment: Thank you all, I think I understand it now, I will write a proper answer to close the post in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\varphi:\mathcal{H}^{\star}\rightarrow\mathbb{K},\quad f\mapsto\lim\limits _{n\rightarrow\infty}f\left(x_{n}\right).$
We know that Hilbert spaces are reflexive, then the canonical mapping
is surjective (from $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathcal{H}^{\star\star}$).

Claim: $\varphi\in\mathcal{H}^{\star\star}$.

Proof of the claim:

We have to show that $\varphi$ is a continuous bounded operator.
Define $\left\{ \varphi\left(f\right)\right\} $ to be a single element
set, containing $\varphi$. By assumption, this set is bounded, for
any $f\in\mathcal{H}^{\star}$. We can now apply Banach-Steinhaus
theorem, and we obtain easily that $\varphi$ is bounded, since $\left\{ \varphi\left(f\right)\right\} $
is bounded aswell. Moreover, we know that norm-bounded sets are weakly
compact, then $\varphi$ is also continuous. So $\varphi$ is element
of $\mathcal{H}^{\star\star}$.

It follows directly that if $\varphi\in\mathcal{H}^{\star\star}$,
then $\varphi\left(f\right)=\lim\limits _{n\rightarrow\infty}f\left(x_{n}\right)=f\left(x\right)$,
since the canonical mapping is surjective.

We have then that for all $f\in\mathcal{H}^{\star}$, $f\left(x_{n}\right)\rightarrow f\left(x\right)$,
so by definition of weak convergence, $x_{n}$ converges weakly to
$x\in\mathcal{H}$.

Answer (score 1):

By corollary 2.4 of Banach-Steinhaus theorem in $\textbf{Brezis}$, we have that $x_n$ is bounded. Then as $H$ is Hilbert, hence reflexive, there exists a $x \in H $ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$ converges weakly to $x$. Then there exists a subsequence $x_{n_j}$ such that $f(x_{n_j}) \rightarrow f(x)$ for all $f \in H^{\star}$. But as $((f(x_n))_{n}$ converges we have that $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$ for all $f \in H^{\star}$.